# Android ExceptionInitializerError Can't Create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I am making an app which parses online xml feed. I have used fragment and tabs.

below is the code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle       savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_file, container, false);
         allPress_listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView_for_all);
         progressBar=(ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

         return v;
       /* return inflater.inflate(R.layout.afragment, container, false);
        listView=(ListView)fi*/
    }  

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
       /* ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Cheese );
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);*/
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {  
           @Override
            public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
              {
                   //Thread.sleep(5000);    
                   new DoSomeTask().execute();                           

              }catch(Exception e){}
                       // myPd_ring.dismiss();
          }
       }).start();

}
```

Problem is when I run the app on Samsung Galaxy Mini having Android version 4.1.2, it run without crashing, but when I run the app on lower versions, it crashes. Below is the error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13631): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-164034
E/AndroidRuntime(13631): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(13631):    at com.sl.sx.APR$1.run(AllReleases.java:74)
E/AndroidRuntime(13631):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
E/AndroidRuntime(13631): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:  Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
E/AndroidRuntime(13631):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
E/AndroidRuntime(13631):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:607)
E/AndroidRuntime(13631):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:607)
E/AndroidRuntime(13631):    at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:190)
E/AndroidRuntime(13631):    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, async tasks should be created and run on the UI thread (see "Threading rules" http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Here are the relevant rules:

- The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
- The task instance must be created on the UI thread.

To solve your problem, you should move `new DoSomeTask().execute();` out of the `Runnable`, or if you insist starting it in a `Runnable` then use `Activity.runOnUiThread()` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

E.g.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    new DoSomeTask().execute();
}
```

Comment: I used the below line                                                             Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); and it  seems that problem is resolved,checking on lower versions

Comment: You don't need to create any handlers here. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that `DoSomeTask` is an AsyncTask which you are trying to start from a background thread. AsyncTasks can be started only from the UI thread.

Change to-

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
       /* ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Cheese );
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);*/
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         new DoSomeTask().execute();    
}
```

Comment: yes DoSomeTask is an AsynctASK. But when I extend Activity,this works fine.Why it is throwing error when I am extending Fragment?

Comment: I think the Activity or Fragment does not make a difference here. It depends on whether you are starting the task from UI thread or background thread.